# Python replace occurrence in file from a list by order

Tags: python

Let's say I have this file :

```
Hi
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hi
Hello
Hi
Hi
```

I want to replace the word 'Hi' in my file by occurences from a list.

Let's say I have this list : ["Ok","No",Yes"]

I want to replace the word 'Hi' by 'Ok' at first then the 2nd occurence of the word 'Hi' should be replaced by 'No' and so on.

Here's what I have tried :

```
with open('myfile.extension') as f:
    for line in f:
        new_line = line.replace('Hi' , 'No', 1)
        print(new_line)
```

I know this won't do the work but even though this replaces all 'Hi' occurences with 'No' instead of just the first occurence.

Why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `iter` with `next`:

```
import re, itertools
c = itertools.cycle(["Ok","No","Yes"])
result = re.sub('Hi', lambda _:next(c), open('filename.txt').read())
```

Output:

```
Ok
Hello
Hello
Hello
No
Hello
Yes
Ok
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of which replacement you need to use next, you can do that with a counter:

```
counter = 0
replacements = ["Ok", "No", "Yes"]

with open('path/to/file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if 'Hi' in line:
            line = line.replace('Hi', replacements[counter % len(replacements)])
            counter += 1
        print(line.strip())
```

**Output**

```
Ok
Hello
Hello
Hello
No
Hello
Yes
Ok
```

By using:

```
new_line = line.replace('Hi' , 'No', 1)
```

You are always replacing `'Hi'` with `'No'`. The [parameter count](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) refers to how many times for the given string, in this case `line`, are you going to apply the replacement.